# Formula for testing DAOs with Hibernate/JPA Mappings and JUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, tdd

I have found many questions related to this, but a lot of the discussion is around using HSQL databases instead of configuring Eclipse and the Command Line to run actual tests.

Say I have the following made-up scenario:

```
@Entity
@Table("Team")
public class Team {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String owner;
    private List<Player> players;

    @Column(name="TEAM_ID")
    public Integer getTeamId() {
       return this.id;
    }

    public void setTeamId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="TEAM_ID")
    public Integer getName() {
       return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    // ... etc.
}
```

And lets say we have the following Data Access Layer:

```
@Repository
public class TeamDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="examplePU")
    EntityManger em;

    public Team saveOrUpdate(Team team) {
        this.em.merge(team);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

I'd like to be able to write an integration test similar to the following:

```
public class TeamIntegrationTest {

    @Resource
    TeamDao teamDao;

    @Test
    public void resourceLoaded() {
        assertNotNull(teamDao);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertTeam() {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.setName("Packers");
        team.setCity("Green Bay");
        teamDao.saveOrUpdate(team);
    }
}
```

What is required to run this in my own development environment before committing to ensure that it is working properly? Please include references to relevant libraries that may help.

In the end, I'd like to create a formula that can be used for future projects (I also believe this to be a goal of many other enterprise developers).

---

## Proposed Formula

Rather than typing this as a solution and nominating myself as the one who provided the answer, I felt it was best to mark the answer that closely met what I was looking for and expand upon it. Configuration is a pain, which is what I was looking to gain knowledge from by asking this question. In the end, I chose to rely on Spring to handle a bunch of annoying things on our behalf.

First of all, the configuration (assuming the `src/{main,test,inttest}/java`, `src/{main,test,inttest}/resources` setup:

```
src/resources/java
|
| - META-INF
|    |
|    | - orm.xml
|    | - persistence.xml
| - applicationContext.xml
| - applicationContext-Integration.xml
```

`orm.xml` does not contain much content, but I experienced problems when it was not there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
</entity-mappings>
```

`Persistence.xml` contains the entities that JPA should know about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitName">
        <class>com.acme.project.className</class>
        <!-- Etc... -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

`applicationContext.xml` contains the bulk of the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Spring configuration for JPA/database/Transactions -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.project.full.package.name" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" p:dataSource-ref="jndiDataSource"
        p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect" />

    <bean id="jndiDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.databaseType.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:url://location:port/databaseName" />
            <property name="username" value="" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true" p:dataSource-ref="jndiDataSource"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnitName" p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect">
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" p:generateDdl="false"
        p:showSql="true" />
```

We are using an EntityManager, so the solution that recommended [AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests.html) would not work for us. Instead, we created the following that pulls in `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` and sets the applicationContext properly.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext-JPA-Integration.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class SpringBasedIntegration { }
```

We created this generic class so that it could be used across other integration test classes,

```
public class TeamIntegrationTest extends SpringBasedIntegration {

    @Resource
    TeamDao vitalDao;

    @Before() 
    public void before() {
        List<Team> teams = teamDao.getKnownValues("...");
        for(Team entry : teams) {
            vitalDao.deleteTeam(team);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() { 
        // vitalDao should be initialized with an entityManger!
    }
```

Now, this has a weakness of not rolling data back so I introduced a hack that will delete known values using the `@Before` method so that each method has a fresh known state. This may work for some, but likely not everyone.

All feedback is welcome. I'd love for the community to have a well documented solution for integration testing JPA/Hibernate and we all know that StackOverflow is the best first result on Google for our queries.

Comment: Not entirely relevant to your question, but rather than `@Test` whether teamDao is properly loaded, you might try using `Assume` ( http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html ) in your tests.

Comment: Very interesting factoid that could be useful in some situations. I'd rather not have tests ignored if something is not properly initialized (i.e. a layer in an integration test is failing)

Answer (score 4):

Give Spring Framework a Try,

You Can Use Spring Transactional Test for your JUNIT classes; it runs the test but every change is rollbacked after the operation finished. You can change this behavior to actually commit, it's up to you.

The magic is made by a class called *AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests* , In Your case you would need to setup an applicationcontext in your local project and run the test with eclipse junit runner.

This is a good tutorial that uses AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests 
http://zenoconsulting.wikidot.com/blog:8

Other Links
http://www.infoq.com/articles/testing-in-spring
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-support-classes-junit44

Answer (score 4):

Some addition to the good material provided by Carlos. If you want to go Java EE compliant and didn't want to bind you application to Spring, you can go with HSQLDB + Maven only.

The tutorials provided by Carlos already talk about these combination, but you don't need Spring if you don't want to. You can just create the PersistentContext programmatically, creating a base JUnit test case that does that for you:

```
@Ignore
public abstract class DaoBaseTestCase {

    private static final String TEST_UNIT_NAME = "test_unit";
    protected static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    protected static EntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void prepareEntityManagerFactory() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(TEST_UNIT_NAME);
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @After
    public abstract void rollbackTransactionAndReleaseEntityManager();

    @AfterClass
    public static void releaseEntityManager() {
        if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        if(entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.close();
        }
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Then you can create getters/setters for the EntityManager in you DAOs to pass the one created in the base DAO test.

Comment: Yes, Spring is not required, you can surely use only JEE compliant code.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently published a lightweight framework called [TestFun-JEE](https://github.com/michaelyaakoby/testfun) for testing EJB+JPA++ code using JUnit - the framework takes care for injecting EJBs and Mockito mocks into your test code without using a container (maybe I should say the framework is mocking a container).

```
@Local
public interface SomeDao {
    SomeEntity save(SomeEntity t);
    List<SomeEntity> getAll();
}

@Stateless
public class SomeDaoImpl implements SomeDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestFun")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public SomeEntity save(SomeEntity t) {
        if (t.getId() == 0) {
            entityManager.persist(t);
        } else {
            entityManager.merge(t);
        }
        return t;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<SomeEntity> getAll() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM SomeEntity AS be");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}

@RunWith(EjbWithMockitoRunner.class)
public class DaoTest {

    @EJB
    private SomeDao dao;

    @Test
    public void saveOne() {
        dao.save(new SomeEntity(0, "1. one", "s"));
        List<SomeEntity> entities = dao.getAll();
        assertEquals(1, entities.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void getMany() {
        dao.save(new SomeEntity(0, "1. one", "s"));
        dao.save(new SomeEntity(0, "2. two", "r"));
        List<SomeEntity> entities = dao.getAll();
        assertEquals(2, entities.size());
        assertThat(entities).
                onProperty("name").
                isEqualTo(Arrays.asList("1. one", "2. two"));//Note, this using org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat
    }

}
```